# Как из двух списков создать список словарей с новыми ключами?

Tags: python

Есть два списка:

```
a = [раз, два, три]
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

Нужно создать список из словарей вида:

```
с = [{"word": 'раз', "count": 1}, {"word": 'два', "count": 2}, {"word": 'три', "count": 3}]
```

Пыталась использовать цикл

```
    spisok = []
    for word in a:
        for v in b:
            spis = {"word": wrd, "count": v}
        spisok.append(spis)
```

Но значения в ключе "count" для всех значений ключа "word" одинаковое, то есть последнее из списка b.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить данную проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

используйте функцию `zip`

```
a = ["раз", "два", "три"]
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = []

for word, count in zip(a, b):
    c.append({"word":word, "count":count})
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 2):

сделайте в лоб

```
a = ['раз', 'два', 'три']
b = [1, 2, 3]

res = [{'word': obj[0], 'count': obj[1]} for obj in zip(a, b)]
print(res)
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Так например

```
a = ['раз', 'два', 'три']
b = [1, 2, 3]
c =[{ 'word' : a[x], 'count' : b[x] } for x in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: спасибо большое